# Edge not rendering SVG Symbol

Tags: svg

I have two pairs of SVG patterns and symbols. The symbol holds and the SVG and the pattern shapes it. I use each pattern as a fill for a Circle.

This approach works fine in chrome but in edge only some svgs render in the circle. Below is an example, on chrome you should see both a shoe and a diamond. On Edge only the diamond renders even thou the approach is the same as the shoe.

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/lpoulter/pen/mqQKLo?editors=1000)

```
<svg width="660" height="600">
  <defs>

<symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="symbol-shoe" viewBox="0 0 45 45">
  </svg>
  ....SVG code 
  </svg>
```

```
<symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="symbol-diamond" viewBox="0 0 45 45">
 <svg> 
    ....SVG code 
 </svg>
</symbol>

  <pattern id="pattern-diamond" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <use xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="6.59" y="6.59" width="31.819" height="31.819" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#symbol-diamond" />

  <pattern id="pattern-shoe" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">    
      <use xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="6.59" y="6.59" width="31.819" height="31.819" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#symbol-shoe" />
  </pattern>

</defs>

<circle fill="url(#pattern-shoe)" cx="150" cy="150" r="60" />

<circle fill="url(#pattern-diamond)" cx="150" cy="400" r="60" />
```

Comment: Another approach might be to not use the symbol but i'm not sure i can size the svg correctly without it. Should add the shoe svg renders in edge without the symbol.

Comment: I've never seen a <SVG> fragment nested inside a symbol before. I don't think that's legal. (Chrome renders a lot of illegal SVG) You might want to use an <image> tag instead and inline the SVG as a data URL.